# Send requests untill the user input is a predetermined value

Tags: c#, input

I want to check if the user input is one of the chars from "menuChars" and repeat the request as long as it doesn't fit. Here is my full code. I marked the actual problem with "===". You can also tell me if you find some other problems or performace improvements.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

namespace AppointmentBook
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      char userKeyPress = showMenue();
      char[] menuChars = { 'e', 'E', 'l', 'L', 'k', 'K', 't', 'T', 's', 'S', 'b', 'B' };

      //Console.WriteLine("\n" + userKeyPress); 


      Calendar calendarObj = new Calendar();

   // ======================= problem area =====================================

      if (menuChars.Contains(userKeyPress))
        {
          do
          {
            Console.WriteLine("\nBitte gültigen Buchstaben eingeben: ");
            userKeyPress = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
          }
          while
            (menuChars.Contains(userKeyPress));
        }

   // ============================================================

      // if START
      if (userKeyPress == 'e' || userKeyPress == 'E')
      {
        calendarObj.addMeeting();
      }

      if (userKeyPress == 'l' || userKeyPress == 'L')
      {
        calendarObj.deleteMeeting();
      }

      if (userKeyPress == 'k' || userKeyPress == 'K')
      {
        calendarObj.showCalendar();
      }

      if (userKeyPress == 't' || userKeyPress == 'T')
      {
        calendarObj.listMeetings();
      }

      if (userKeyPress == 's' || userKeyPress == 'S')
      {
        calendarObj.statistic();
      }

      if (userKeyPress == 'b' || userKeyPress == 'B')
      {
        calendarObj.endProgram();
      }
    }

    static public char showMenue()
    {
      ConsoleKeyInfo readInput;

      Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
      Console.Write("\nWillkommen im Kalender!");

      Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
      Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
      Console.WriteLine("\n\nDatum heute: {0:d}", DateTime.Now);
      Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

      Console.Write("\nMenü\n");

      Console.Write("\n  - Termin (e)intragen");
      Console.Write("\n  - Termin (l)öschen");
      Console.Write("\n  - (K)alender anzeigen");
      Console.Write("\n  - (T)erminliste ausgeben");
      Console.Write("\n  - (S)tatistik");
      Console.Write("\n  - (B)eenden");

      Console.Write("\n\nIhre Wahl: ");

      readInput = Console.ReadKey();
      return readInput.KeyChar;
    }
  }



  class Calendar
  { 
    public Calendar() //Konstruktor
    {

    }

    public void addMeeting()
    {
    var dateFormats = new[] {"dd.MM.yy", "dd-MM-yy", "dd/MM/yy"};

    Console.Write("\n\nHinweis: Erlaubes Datumformat: TT.MM.YYYY");
    Console.Write("\nDatum für Termin festlegen: ");

    string readAddMeeting = Console.ReadLine();
    DateTime scheduleDate;

    bool validDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(
        readAddMeeting,
        dateFormats,
        DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo,
        DateTimeStyles.None, 
        out scheduleDate);

    if (validDate)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Das Datum {0} ist gültig.", scheduleDate.ToShortDateString());
      }
    else
      {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("-- Fehler! -- Ungültiges Datumformat: \"{0}\"", readAddMeeting);
      }
    }

    public void deleteMeeting()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Termin löschen");
      Console.WriteLine("=======================");
    }

    public void /*Rückgabetyp*/ showCalendar() // Funktion
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Kalender anzeigen");
      Console.WriteLine("=======================");
    }

    public void listMeetings()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Terminliste ausgeben");
      Console.WriteLine("=======================");
    }

    public void statistic()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Statistik anzeigen");
      Console.WriteLine("=======================");
    }

    public void endProgram()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Programm beenden");
      Console.WriteLine("=======================");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing your evaluation before the while loop. In addition assign an empty character to `userKeyPress` and call the `showMenue()` method manually, so couldn't you do this instead:

```
char userKeyPress = '-';
showMenue();
while (!menuChars.Contains(userKeyPress))
{
   Console.WriteLine("\nBitte gültigen Buchstaben eingeben: ");
   userKeyPress = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
}
```

Comment: One answer that worked perfectly. Thanks! I deleted the showMenue(); from your code. Otherwise the whole menu would pop up every time you type a wrong char.

Comment: It shouldn't? You sure it's not because you have declared it at the top?

Comment: Okay I did it like you imaginated. But both works fine.